# Amazon Skill register oauth missing redirect_uri

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing an Amazon Skill that I want hooked up with a google account via oauth2.  In my edit skill page, I configured it with my client id, an authorization url and token url from the oauth playground, and made it an authoritative grant with my secret and authentication scheme of "http basic", which is recommended.

I tested my client id/secret in the oauth playground and it works as I expect it to, but when I go to sign in on the Alexa App, I get a "missing redirect_uri" error.  Looking at the link in the popup, it looks like the following:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=custom_client_id&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email

Why is it missing the redirect_uri parameter?  I can't change it on the skills page, it's set, and I added it to my valid redirect_uri lists on the google console.  Anyone else seen this issue before?

Comment: I *hacked* around it by hand-changing the url generated by alexa.amazon.com to include the correct redirect_uri, and it worked. That's silly.  Is there a bug with Amazon's skill stuff?

Answer (score 0):

An easier version of what jking31cs is saying is to include ?redirect_uri= ...
In your base URL. So if you provide them Oath.com/auth as your authorization URL, instead try Oath.com/auth?redirect_uri=

The redirect URI is constant, so this is a good fix until amazon bothers fixing this. It's only an issue on custom skills.

Answer (score 0):

They've fixed the issue with an update to the Alexa App :D